# Counting the number of matches between an "answer key" row and a "student response" row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row containing an answer key for a multiple choice exam and then below that a number of rows containing the answers from students.

A very simple question: how can I count the number of "matches" between each student response row and the answer key row?

Example:

```
Answer key | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
Bob        | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | <some formula magic that would give me '3'>
Steve      | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | <some formula magic that would give me '0'>
Jen        | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | <some formula magic that would give me '6'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick for me: `=arrayformula(sum(B$1:G$1=B2:G4))`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the suggested `=arrayformula(sum(B$1:G$1=B2:G4))` did not work for me.

I had to use `=arrayformula(sum(if(B$1:G$1=B2:G4,1,0)))`.